# How to view permissions for RSA Key Container

Tags: .net, encryption, rsa

I've created an RSA Machine-Store container as a non-administrator, and assigned Full Control to myself, as well as read access to other accounts.

I want to be able to programatically view the ACL for the key container.  When I attempt to do so with the code below, I get the following exception even though I am owner of the key container and have Full Control:

```
System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException: The process does not possess the 'SeSecurityPrivilege' privilege which is required for this operation.
   at System.Security.AccessControl.Privilege.ToggleState(Boolean enable)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeySetSecurityInfo(SafeProvHandle hProv, AccessControlSections accessControlSections)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CspKeyContainerInfo.get_CryptoKeySecurity()
   ...
```

I can view the privileges by using Windows Explorer or CACLS to view the key file in `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\...\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`, so it appears that my account has the required privilege.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
cp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt | CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey | CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
cp.KeyContainerName = containerName;

using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp))
{
    // PrivilegeNotHeldException thrown at next line while
    // dereferencing CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity
    if (rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity != null)
    {
        foreach (CryptoKeyAccessRule rule in rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)))
        {
           ... process rule
        }
    }
}
```

There's [a question with a similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570042/using-c-to-get-a-list-of-acls-for-servers-and-mapped-drives), but I can't see any way to apply the answer to my situation.

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspkeycontainerinfo.cryptokeysecurity(v=vs.90).aspx), the `CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity` property:

> Gets a CryptoKeySecurity object that represents access rights and audit rules for a container.

I want an object that represents access rights but not audit rules (as I don't have the privilege for audit rules).

**UPDATE**

I've found a workaround, which is to locate the file containing the key container and inspect its ACL.  I'm not entirely happy with this as it depends on undocumented implementation details of the cryptography classes (e.g. presumably wouldn't work on Mono), and would still be interested in a better solution.

```
... Initialize cp as above

CspKeyContainerInfo info = new CspKeyContainerInfo(cp);
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), 
    "Microsoft\\Crypto\\RSA\\MachineKeys\\" + info.UniqueKeyContainerName);
FileSecurity fs = new FileInfo(path).GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in fs.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)))
{
    ... process rules
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[As you can see](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/icspasymmetricalgorithm.cs,200) in the .NET Framework reference source, `CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity` is hardcoded to ask for `AccessControlSections.All`.

Besides using internal implementation details of CSP to locate the file, which is understandably undesirable, you have two options.

#### Option 1: Reimplement from scratch

This is the same tack you must take to [list key containers](https://gist.github.com/jnm2/258a422cd17b9f951ef3ad6244e28519), for example.
This is the ideal solution because it does not rely on internal implementation details of either the cryptographic service provider or the .NET Framework and runtime. The only difference between this and option 2 is that it will not attempt to assert the SeSecurityPrivilege (you'll get an InvalidOperationException as though the object has no security descriptor), and it will throw Win32Exception for all other errors. I kept it simple.

Usage:

```
var cryptoKeySecurity =
    GetCryptoKeySecurity(containerName, true, AccessControlSections.All & ~AccessControlSections.Audit);
```

Implementation:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

public static class CryptographicUtils
{
    public static CryptoKeySecurity GetCryptoKeySecurity(string containerName, bool machine, AccessControlSections sections)
    {
        var securityInfo = (SecurityInfos)0;

        if ((sections & AccessControlSections.Owner) != 0) securityInfo |= SecurityInfos.Owner;
        if ((sections & AccessControlSections.Group) != 0) securityInfo |= SecurityInfos.Group;
        if ((sections & AccessControlSections.Access) != 0) securityInfo |= SecurityInfos.DiscretionaryAcl;
        if ((sections & AccessControlSections.Audit) != 0) securityInfo |= SecurityInfos.SystemAcl;

        if (!CryptAcquireContext(
            out CryptoServiceProviderHandle provider,
            containerName,
            null,
            PROV.RSA_FULL,
            machine ? CryptAcquireContextFlags.MACHINE_KEYSET : 0))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
        using (provider)
        {
            var size = 0;
            if (!CryptGetProvParam(provider, PP.KEYSET_SEC_DESCR, null, ref size, securityInfo))
                throw new Win32Exception();

            if (size == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("No security descriptor available.");

            var buffer = new byte[size];

            if (!CryptGetProvParam(provider, PP.KEYSET_SEC_DESCR, buffer, ref size, securityInfo))
                throw new Win32Exception();

            return new CryptoKeySecurity(new CommonSecurityDescriptor(false, false, buffer, 0));
        }
    }


    #region P/invoke
    // ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Local
    // ReSharper disable ClassNeverInstantiated.Local
    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool CryptAcquireContext(out CryptoServiceProviderHandle hProv, string pszContainer, string pszProvider, PROV dwProvType, CryptAcquireContextFlags dwFlags);

    private sealed class CryptoServiceProviderHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        private CryptoServiceProviderHandle() : base(true)
        {
        }

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return CryptReleaseContext(handle, 0);
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool CryptReleaseContext(IntPtr hProv, uint dwFlags);
    }

    private enum PROV : uint
    {
        RSA_FULL = 1
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum CryptAcquireContextFlags : uint
    {
        VERIFYCONTEXT = 0xF0000000,
        NEWKEYSET = 0x8,
        DELETEKEYSET = 0x10,
        MACHINE_KEYSET = 0x20,
        SILENT = 0x40,
        DEFAULT_CONTAINER_OPTIONAL = 0x80
    }


    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private static extern bool CryptGetProvParam(CryptoServiceProviderHandle hProv, PP dwParam, [Out] byte[] pbData, ref int dwDataLen, SecurityInfos dwFlags);

    private enum PP : uint
    {
        KEYSET_SEC_DESCR = 8
    }

    // ReSharper restore UnusedMember.Local
    // ReSharper restore ClassNeverInstantiated.Local
    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
    #endregion
}
```

#### Option 2: Reflection

You could simulate what the `CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity` does, but specify whatever value of `AccessControlSections` you want. This relies on implementation details internal to the .NET Framework and CLR and will very likely not work on other BCL implementations and CLRs, such as .NET Core's. Future updates to the .NET Framework and desktop CLR could also render this option broken. That said, it does work.

Usage:

```
var cryptoKeySecurity =
    GetCryptoKeySecurity(cp, AccessControlSections.All & ~AccessControlSections.Audit);
```

Implementation:

```
public static CryptoKeySecurity GetCryptoKeySecurity(CspParameters parameters, AccessControlSections sections)
{
    var mscorlib = Assembly.Load("mscorlib");
    var utilsType = mscorlib.GetType("System.Security.Cryptography.Utils", true);

    const uint silent = 0x40;
    var args = new[]
    {
        parameters,
        silent,
        mscorlib.GetType("System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandle", true)
            .GetMethod("get_InvalidHandle", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Invoke(null, null)
    };

    if ((int)utilsType
            .GetMethod("_OpenCSP", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Invoke(null, args) != 0)
    {
        throw new CryptographicException("Cannot open the cryptographic service provider with the given parameters.");
    }
    using ((SafeHandle)args[2])
    {
        return (CryptoKeySecurity)utilsType
            .GetMethod("GetKeySetSecurityInfo", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Invoke(null, new[] { args[2], sections });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis.  The P/Invoke method to list key containers is interesting.