# Location of container for public and private keys in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, private-key, public-key

I am trying to store my public and private keys in a container using following code:

```
CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
cp.KeyContainerName = "Test";
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
```

What I'd like to know is the location of the container. Is the location of the container in the file system?

Comment: Most possibly in the directory of your .exe

Comment: no i dint get any new file inside my exe directory.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll find the key files in the following directory (*):

```
Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), 
    @"Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys")
```

You can get the filename for a given key as follows:

```
CspParameters cp = ...;
CspKeyContainerInfo info = new CspKeyContainerInfo(cp);
string fileName = info.UniqueKeyContainerName;
```

I don't believe this information is documented, so if you use it you'll be relying on undocumented implementation details which may not work in future versions of Windows.  Unfortunately, it's sometimes necessary to use it; for example [as noted in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659402/how-to-view-permissions-for-rsa-key-container), I don't think there's any other reliable way to view permissions for an RSA Key Container from a non-privileged account.

(*) that's for machine keys.  User-specific keys are presumably under `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`

Comment: Thanks..you are correct i couldn't find the documented information on MSDN.In future it may be obsolete.:D.Thanks again

Comment: For me this path resolved to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`

Comment: User-specific keys are in a directory under Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData

Answer (score 4):

I used [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) and [Sn.exe (Strong Name Tool)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23(v=vs.110).aspx) to learn the location of the folder on my Windows 7 machine that contains my key files and thereby confirm the information in [Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10690349/1497596).

First, I ran Process Monitor and specified the following filter:

```
Column    Relation    Value    Action
---------------------------------------
Path      contains    crypto   Include
```

I then ran Strong Name Tool (`sn.exe`)<sup>†</sup> to extract the public key from the key pair in my container `VS_KEY_773685D47C32F8C7` and export it to `public_key.snk`:

```
sn.exe -pc VS_KEY_773685D47C32F8C7 public_key.snk
```

After doing so I noted that Process Monitor indicated that `sn.exe` made several access requests to the folder:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys
```

...and the file that contains my public and private keys for my container named `VS_KEY_773685D47C32F8C7`:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\74c2c10a37baa69f7969c7144db5805d_c55067c2-4a01-4792-9d70-d7a6e4799447
```

---

<sup>†</sup>`sn.exe` can be conveniently run via the [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx).