# Get Certificate Absolute Path using UniqueKeyContainerName

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate

Given a certificate thumbprint, I want to find the absolute file path to the certificate on the local file-system.

This snippet almost always works.

```
$thumb    = <mythumbprint string>

$cert     = Get-ChildItem "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $thumb};
$keyName  = (($cert.PrivateKey).CspKeyContainerInfo).UniqueKeyContainerName
$keyPath  = $env:ProgramData + "\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\"
$fullPath = $keyPath+$keyName
```

It fails on certs where the PrivateKey is not Exportable. When marked as NOT Exportable, the `$cert.PrivateKey` is no longer accessible and consequently unable to build the certificate's complete path.

Is there a powershell alternative for determining a certificate's UniqueKeyContainerName?

**UPDATE:**
All the certs I am concerned about have private keys. The problem is that I cannot assume they are marked as exportable. If NOT marked exportable, .PrivateKey cannot be referenced. I need another way to get UniqueKeyContainerName without chaining through .Privatekey

Comment: Ever figure this out? I am trying to script cert permissions for a deployment and my keys aren't exportable and I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be very little useful information on this topic, let alone for PowerShell 5.1 *and* 7.1 (.NET Core). Hopefully this [helps](https://xkcd.com/979/) someone.

I've adapted this from [Vadims Podāns 'Retrieve CNG key container name and unique name'](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/retrieve-cng-key-container-name-and-unique-name.aspx)

Please note:

- Example use of Cmdlet: `Get-Item 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My\FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF' | Get-CertificateContainerAbsolutePath`
- I cheated and just searched for key file recursively under Microsoft Crypto directory hierarchy instead of searching correct specific sub-directories
- Despite use of CNG Provider, this seems to work against a test CryptoAPI provided key I created
- I tested this on Powershell 5.1 and 7.1 on Windows.

```powershell
if(-not ('EmbeddedTemporary.PKITools' -as [type])) {
    $PKIToolsDefinition = @"
[DllImport("Crypt32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool CertGetCertificateContextProperty(
    IntPtr pCertContext,
    uint dwPropId,
    IntPtr pvData,
    ref uint pcbData
);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string pwszContainerName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string pwszProvName;
    public uint dwProvType;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint cProvParam;
    public IntPtr rgProvParam;
    public uint dwKeySpec;
}
[DllImport("ncrypt.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int NCryptOpenStorageProvider(
    ref IntPtr phProvider,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string pszProviderName,
    uint dwFlags
);
[DllImport("ncrypt.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int NCryptOpenKey(
    IntPtr hProvider,
    ref IntPtr phKey,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string pszKeyName,
    uint dwLegacyKeySpec,
    uint dwFlags
);
[DllImport("ncrypt.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int NCryptGetProperty(
    IntPtr hObject,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string pszProperty,
    byte[] pbOutput,
    int cbOutput,
    ref int pcbResult,
    int dwFlags
);
[DllImport("ncrypt.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int NCryptFreeObject(
    IntPtr hObject
);
"@
    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $PKIToolsDefinition -Namespace 'EmbeddedTemporary' -Name 'PKITools'
}

Function Get-CertificateContainerAbsolutePath {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValuefromPipeline)]
        $Certificate
    )
    $CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID = 0x2 # from Wincrypt.h header file
    $pcbData = 0
    [EmbeddedTemporary.PKITools]::CertGetCertificateContextProperty($Certificate.Handle, $CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, [IntPtr]::Zero, [ref]$pcbData) | Out-Null
    $pvData = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::AllocHGlobal($pcbData)
    [EmbeddedTemporary.PKITools]::CertGetCertificateContextProperty($Certificate.Handle, $CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, $pvData, [ref]$pcbData) | Out-Null
    $keyProv = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStructure($pvData, [type][EmbeddedTemporary.PKITools+CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO])
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::FreeHGlobal($pvData) | Out-Null

    $CngProvider = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngProvider]::new($keyProv.pwszProvName)
    $CngKey = [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey]::Open($keyProv.pwszContainerName, $CngProvider, [System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyOpenOptions]::MachineKey)
    $UniqueName = $CngKey.UniqueName
    $CngKey.Dispose()

    $Certificates = Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path -Path $Env:ProgramData -ChildPath 'Microsoft\Crypto') -Recurse -Filter $UniqueName
    $Certificates.FullName
}
```

Comment: This is also relevant but Answer is not helpful for PowerShell 7.1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659402/how-to-view-permissions-for-rsa-key-container

Comment: I dug around on this topic and found the following discussion which spoke to the changes in [.net vs. core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35920)

Answer (score 0):

This works in PowerShell 5.1 only.

```
    $cert = Get-Item -Path Cert:/LocalMachine/My/<thumbprint>
    $fileName = $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
    $path = "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\$fileName"
```

7.1 implements the PrivateKey property using a different type:
PowerShell 5.1

```
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $cert.PrivateKey.GetType()

    IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
    -------- -------- ----                                     --------
    True     False    RSACryptoServiceProvider                 
    System.Security.Cryptography.RSA
```

PowerShell 7.x

```
    PS C:\Windows\System32> $cert.PrivateKey.GetType()

    IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
    -------- -------- ----                                     --------
    True     False    RSACng                                   
    System.Security.Cryptography.RSA
```

Comment: Mentioned above in a comment, a [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35920) that talks about the different types

Answer (score -1):

If I'm following you, you can filter certs that have a HasPrivateKey:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\my | 
Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $thumb -and $_.HasPrivateKey} | ForEach-Object {  
    Join-Path $env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys $_.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not help. HasPrivateKey will evaluate to $true. The problem is that if the cert was NOT marked as Exportable when it was generated then .PrivateKey fails.