# CryptoKeySecurity returns null

Tags: .net, powershell, ssl

I am trying to modify access rules for particular `$cert` with the following code:

```
$csp = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters (
    $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType, 
    $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName, 
    $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName)

$csp.Flags = [System.Security.Cryptography.CspProviderFlags]::UseExistingKey -bor [System.Security.Cryptography.CspProviderFlags]::UseMachineKeyStore
$csp.CryptoKeySecurity = $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity
$csp.KeyNumber = $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyNumber

$access = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyAccessRule (
    $identity, 
    [System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeyRights]::GenericRead, 
    [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow)

$csp.CryptoKeySecurity.AddAccessRule($access)
```

But it throws an exception on last line because `$csp.CryptoKeySecurity` is null. While debugging it turned out `$cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.CryptoKeySecurity` is null as well. However, the hard part is this only happens on 1 out of 5 machines, is not dependent on OS version, nor PS version, happens in our prod environment only, why... ? FYI `$cert.PrivateKey` is not null, neither `$cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo`.

Comment: .NET Framework reference code seems to show a non-null case always, https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/icspasymmetricalgorithm.cs,184

Comment: @LexLi after looking at the code you posted and rewriting the code into C# it turbned out it blows up on `kp.Demand();` because I do not posses necessary privilege - "Manage auditing and security log", hence `null` in PS and exception in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem was in different configuration of security settings on our production environment. On my machine, setting `Manage auditing and security log` was set to `Administrators`, while on server it was different, just our OPS people. Found out about this after rewriting the code into C#, which throws an exception, unlike PS, which just silently returns null.

> The process does not possess the ‘SeSecurityPrivilege’ privilege which is required for this operation.

For how to work around this issue see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7659402/3242721).