# How can I find the users which a shared folder, shared to programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get list of users that a folders is shared to programatically?

I need a class or a method to do this, Is there any library or API for this?

I have a shared folder like `\\faridb\TestSharedFolder` an I want to get list of users (also in domain) that this folder is shared to.

The shared folder is on my own machine.

How can I get this list?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136539/determining-if-a-folder-is-shared-in-net

Comment: @ssilas777: The solution that mentioned couldnt help me.

Comment: Perhaps [this SO answer][1] might help?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570042/using-c-sharp-to-get-a-list-of-acls-for-servers-and-mapped-drives

Comment: This question is NOT duplicate with "Determining if a folder is shared in .NET"